# What should I unit test in my ASP.NET MVC3 project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing, nunit

I am new to unit testing.  I have a web application using asp.net mvc3 and s#arp lite.  I want to add unit test to this application. so far, I have a test for each action in the controller class.  Just curious, what else I need to test?  Does view need to be tested too?

another question, all the testing example I found online are using moq or other tools to make fake data.  Should we also test again the real database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should neither unit test views nor against a real database. Use unit tests for your code-level artifacts like controller actions, action filters, html helpers, models, anything written in C#.

For testing a real database and views, look to integration tests. Integration tests are not like unit tests, but you can still execute them using a unit test framework like nunit. Basically, you just write test code to drive a browser using something like Selenium WebDriver or Watin. But these are not really unit tests, they are integration tests, end-to-end tests, or user acceptance tests.

Answer (score 4):

"Test until bored"

That being said, be wary of doing most of your testing via integration testing. 
In other words, test 1 thing at a time.
For example. you might be interested in testing

- Controller Logic
- Routing Logic
- Database
- Loading Methods
- Views

but don't test 2 or more in the same test. 
 So if you test the Controller logic, pass in or mock out the dataobjects being used.

That being said, you might also be interested in the "how" to test these parts. I'll cover 3 parts below (Database, loading functions, Views)

**Database**

there are really only 2 things you need to test in a database

1. is it connected?
2. is it's schema correct

For connected, I prefer an echo test

```
Assert.AreEqual(42, QuerySingleResult("Select 42"));
```

The are many ways to test the metadata of the database, but if you have a version number in being stored, you can simply test that. this also makes upgrading path easier.

```
Assert.AreEqual(6, QuerySingleResult("Select version From Schema"));
```

**Loading Functions**

There are many ways to test loading functions (i'll show a simple one here) but they all depend on isolating the loading into a function.

Testing linq to ...
Let's say you have

```
var people = From db in new EntityFrameworkContext().People Where ...... Select ....
```

if you split this into 2 functions

```
IEnumerable<People> LoadPeople()
{
 return LoadPeople( new EntityFrameworkContext().People);
}
IEnumerable<People> LoadPeople(IEnumerable<People> fromPeople)
{
 return From db in fromPeople Where ...... Select ....

}
```

This is now easy to test.

**Views**

While views are easy to test, there's a lot of details. I'll refer you to the video for everything: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SttlPzwJw3U

but the 2 important parts are

1) the test

```
MvcApprovals.VerifyMvcPage(new YourController().YourTestAction
```

2) a test seam in the controller

```
public ActionResult YourTestAction()
{
  // setup your model
  return View("viewpage", model);
}
```

Happy Testing!

Answer (score 2):

Test anything that may contain a bug.  Views are somewhat harder to test, but it's not a bad idea.  IF you're looking for specifics, test any custom attributes, events, static methods, extension methods, and whatever other utilities.

If you're testing against a database make sure it's a database dedicated to testing.  Many ORMs provide a way for you to mock the database as well.

I personally am a fan of Ayehde's (www.ayende.com) products and use Rhino.Mocks and RavenDB as my mocking framework and database respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no logic in the view you probably don't need to unit test them. You may want to supplement your unit test with a few end-to-end tests covering important basic scenarios using e.g. Selenium.

Yes, you want to having integration tests that go to the database alongside your unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, we can't tell you what to unit test, because you're testing YOUR code, not the framework code.  And we don't know what your code does.  Only you do.

There is no point in unit testing framework code, it's already been tested.  You need to concentrate on writing tests that cover your logic.